# Android library is not working with Java 8

Tags: java, android, java-8, noclassdeffounderror, android-library

## Problem

Since I switched to **Java 8** in [Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) the [ShineButton library](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton) is not working in my project anymore.

---

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener$$CC;`

I receive this error when using a `ShineButton` in my application at [this](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/blob/master/shinebuttonlib/src/main/java/com/sackcentury/shinebuttonlib/ShineView.java#L118) part of the library exactly. Since this error occurred with my update to *Java 8* and I read about some similar error with *Java 8* I am quite sure that it is the factor, which causes the problem.

### Goal

I would love to have a solution that allows the library to work with **Java 8**, because I like both the library and the functions that *Java 8* delivers. I am not quite sure how to tackle this problem because i could not find any information on the `NoClassDefFoundError` and which exact relationship it has to *Java 8*.

#### Extra Information

I am building my project in Android Studio 3.0 *Canary 4* in Android O and I am using version `0.1.7` of `ShineButton`.

The error occurs when pressing a `ShineButton` with it executing its animation.

I already [issued this on GitHub](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/issues/26), but I have not seen any response to my own nor even older issues.
Recently I also started an [issue to the Android developer team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62800181).

Comment: That's more likely a problem of AS 3.0 and its Java 8 support (both still `early access`) rather than a real Java 8 problem.

Comment: Note that I'm facing the same issue in the library: `com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0`. This started appearing after the migration to Java 8 (exception thrown is: `UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener$$CC;`)

Comment: Related github issue for the library mentioned in the comment before: [https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/issues/130](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/issues/130)

Comment: @Peter I guess that I will add this to the Android issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a little update. My error was fixed quite some time ago. I think it was with *Canary 5-6* and the dependency updates.

Answer (score 3):

open D8 in `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableD8.desugaring= true
android.enableD8=true
```

see:https://jakewharton.com/androids-java-8-support/

**Or Code like below:**

```
private Animator.AnimatorListener mAnimatorListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation, boolean isReverse) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation, boolean isReverse) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
```

**the key is override:**

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation, boolean isReverse) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation, boolean isReverse) {

}
```